# Stats page squishes ads to the old 220px width

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, community-promotion-ads

> Note: I've already mentioned this issue in a comment on Meta.CodeReview, but I thought I'd document it here on the main Stack Exchange meta.

I love the new 300px community ads format.

[image: a Code Review community ad post]

Problem is, the [stats page](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6539) that's showing ads with 6+ upvotes is still showing the ads in the old 220px format, which looks... odd.

[image: Squished ducks of Code Review]

Comment: Looks like this has just been fixed.

Comment: On mobile at least, the last ad on a row is bleeding off the edge of the white area of the page, which doesn't look right either. New bug?

Answer (score 6):

Well, we fixed it briefly, but we had to revert it back because it turns out the stats page uses the same ad code as the running ads, and the change was [causing the old ads to be stretched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273255/please-dont-stretch-the-old-community-ads). When the 2016 ads go live, we'll switch the code back and the stats page will pick up the change as well.

The page also probably will need to be adjusted to only put three on a single row. We'll worry about that when the time comes.

Comment: When are 2016 ads scheduled to go live? [I thought they were already](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6550/23788)!

Comment: @Mat'sMug it's Grace Note's decision: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273255/please-dont-stretch-the-old-community-ads#comment888056_273255

Comment: That's really unfortunate. I would have loved to be able to take a look at how the new ads look in their final version (especially since the meta answer doesn't scale retina-optimized ads down to the proper size) before they go live.

Comment: It should be possible to make this work with both the new and the old ad dimensions, simply by omitting the `height` attribute from the HTML and letting the browser determine it based on the image file's aspect ratio. See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275957) for details.

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix that works with both the new *and* the old ad dimensions would be to simply omit the `height` attribute from the `<img>` tags, and only specify the width.  This way, browsers will scale the images to the desired width, *while keeping their aspect ratio*.

In fact, I even found a way to override the `height` attributes using CSS, like this:

```css
a[href*="/ads/ct/"] img {
    height: auto;
}
```

I've included this CSS patch in the current stable version (v1.44) of my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script.  It even works on sites that currently have ads with mixed dimensions, [like this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/6024):

> [image: Screenshot]